# Get the actual type instead of the type parameter when java 1.6 annotation processing

Tags: java, apt, annotation-processing

Given these two classes

```
public class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass<Cow> {
  ...
}

public abstract class MyAbstractClass<Foo_ extends AbstractFoo> {
  ...
  Key<Foo_> foo;
  ...
}
```

If I run this code in an annotation processor, I don't get the result I want.

```
for (VariableElement fieldElement : ElementFilter.fieldsIn(env.getElementUtils().getAllMembers((TypeElement)entityElement))) {
    String fieldType = fieldElement.asType().toString();
}
```

env is a ProcessingEnvironment.
entityElement is an Element.  (MyClass)

fieldType is set to `Key<Foo_>`.

What do I need to call to get fieldType set to `Key<MyClass>`?

Comment: Which TypeElement is being processed when you get that output? The one for class `MyAbstractClass`?

Answer (score 3):

The type of `foo` is `Foo_` just as it is in the code. I think instead of `Key<MyClass>` you mean `Key<Cow>` as that is the type argument used there. Using the [Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html) utility, you can get the field's type as seen from the subclass `MyClass` by using the method [getDeclaredType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Types.html#getDeclaredType%28javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement,%20javax.lang.model.type.TypeMirror...%29)

```
// these are the types as declared in the source
System.out.println(fieldElement.asType());      // Key<Foo_>
System.out.println(t.getSuperclass());          // MyAbstractClass<Cow>

// extract the type argument of MyAbstractClass
TypeMirror superClassParameter = ((DeclaredType) t.getSuperclass()).getTypeArguments().get(0);
System.out.println(superClassParameter);        // Cow

// use the type argument and the field's type's type element to construct the fields actual type
DeclaredType fieldType = typeUtils.getDeclaredType(
        (TypeElement) typeUtils.asElement(fieldElement.asType()), superClassParameter);

System.out.println(fieldType);                   // Key<Cow>
```